# CSS alignment of select and image on the same line

Tags: css, alignment

I'm trying to aling a select menu with an image which is a submit button. My code is as followS:

```
<form action="index.php">

 <p>

 <select name="ID">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>

 <input type="image" class="arrwSubmit" src="/images/go-green.png">

 </p>

</form>
```

Arrow submit has a class which floats the image left. However this causes the problem that the image is displayed to the left of the select, I want it to be to the right and on the same line. If I apply the same class to the select element then the slect and arrow display fine but then the next element (a table) also appears on the same line.

How can I align as follows:

Line 1 = select > image (submit)

Line 2 = table

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: I'll put one together and post it a little later....